# Comprehensive /etc/auto.disks script for autofs that takes into consideration all mounted disks, including NTFS and FAT32?

Tags: linux, automounting, autofs

Does anyone have a more comprehensive `/etc/auto.disks` script for `autofs` that takes into consideration all mounted disks, even NTFS, FAT32? So all that's needed to mount any attached drive is `ls /mnt/sda1` or `ls /mnt/sdb2`?

[This guide](http://phaq.phunsites.net/2008/01/24/an-autofs-executable-map-to-automount-device-nodes/) along the line of what I'm looking for, except this guy only accesses ext3 drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
key="$1"
[ -b /dev/${key} ] && {
        fstype=`sudo blkid -s TYPE "/dev/$key" -o value`
        opts="-fstype=$fstype,rw"
        echo "$opts :/dev/${key}";
}
```